# can not add product to the cart in virtuemart

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

i am a new joomla developer.

I have a problem in virtuemart:

When I add stockable vairants custom field to the products, the product didn’t adding to the cart !!

any solution please ??

Answer (score 1):

We could really do with more info on this, as there are a few possible causes.

Just for next time, info like...

- What Joomla version
- What VirtueMart version
- What Joomla tenmplate is it
- A link, if possible or some code to review

...would be really useful.

However, when I've come across this, the most frequent cause has been a jQuery conflict.  So perhaps jQuery is being loaded multiple times.  Often the solution is to set VirtueMart to not load jQuery.

There is checkbox for this in VirtueMart "Configuration" screen, under the "Templates" tab, within the "Activate Css Styles & Javascripts" section, a checkbox called "Using the VirtueMart jQuery".  Just untick this box.

There is some background on the VirtueMart website on the [General JS-Problems with templates and jQuery](http://dev.virtuemart.net/projects/virtuemart/wiki/General_JS-Problems_with_templates_and_jQuery) page.

Answer (score 0):

it is sure that the problem is of jquery. jquery is required to run once only. I solved my problem by disabling one of the third party extension of slider. I had read also that some person had solved it by disabling the menubar extension. So problem is with running jquery twice.